# Template parameter shadowing with GCC 5

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I had the (bad) surprise to discover that the following code does not compile using CGG 5 or below, although it works like a charm with clang 4 or CGG 6 (and higher).

I don't really see what's going wrong, and what it shadowing template parameters of class `B`. More importantly I don't see how I should tweak it so that it compiles with older versions of GCC...

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, int N>
struct A {
public:
    std::array<T, 3> coordinates = { };
};

template <typename T, int N>
class B {
public:
    A<T, N> *myA = new A<T, N>();
};
```

Compiler outputs:

```
<source>:12:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
     A<T, N> *myA = new A<T, N>();
                             ^
<source>:12:29: error: declaration of 'A<T, N> B<T, N>::N'
<source>:9:23: error:  shadows template parm 'int N'
 template <typename T, int N>
                       ^
<source>:12:30: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
     A<T, N> *myA = new A<T, N>();
                              ^
<source>:12:26: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
     A<T, N> *myA = new A<T, N>();
                          ^
<source>:4:8: error: provided for 'template<class T, int N> struct A'
 struct A {
        ^
Compiler exited with result code 1
```

Comment: `vector` is not a pointer.

Comment: @JérémiPanneton You are right, that was a typo in the question, but not the answer to my problem :). I renamed it `myA`, and typed it as a pointer to an A.

Comment: @J2b Can you update the compiler output too?

Comment: @JérémiPanneton Done! Not much changed, only the variable name.

Comment: Here's the bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52595.   @n.m You didn't use GCC 5...

Comment: The compiler’s name is GCC, which stands for GNU Compiler Collection.

Comment: Adding parents around new expression seems to workaround the bug: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/Z3aMy2).

Comment: @n.m. You used clang.

Comment: @interjay hmm so ideone doesn't tell correctly what compiler it uses.

Comment: @n.m. It says it uses GCC 6.3 or clang 4.0 depending on which one you choose (you see this when mousing over the language). I think the values returned for `__GNUC_*` by clang are meaningless.

Comment: @interjay i don't see it on mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [is a GCC5 bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52595). You can work around it in various ways. The simplest is probably to add parentheses around the new expression, as pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170743/template-parameter-shadowing-with-gcc-5/45171540#comment77311123_45170743):

```
template <typename T, int N>
class B {
public:
    A<T, N> *myA = (new A<T, N> ());
};
```

Another way, perhaps a good idea on its own if you use the type a lot, would be to add `using a_type = A<T, N>;` to the class, and then saying `new a_type`:

```
template <typename T, int N>
class B {
private:
    using a_type = A<T, N>;
public:
    A<T, N> *myA = new a_type();
};
```

Although it doesn’t seem to be necessary, I added a `main` function to ensure template instantiation just in case that affected the bug:

```
int main() {
    B<int, 5> b1, b2;
    b1.myA->coordinates = {{1, 2, 3}};
    return b2.myA->coordinates.size();
}
```

Additionally, I assume these are just artifacts of making a minimal example, but just in case, a few additional points:

- Your `class B` has a memory leak: it never `delete`s the pointers it `new`s.
- Depending on coding style, it may be more idiomatic to initialize the variable in the constructor if it has a complex initialization, unless it’s supposed to be static.
- Based on just what you’ve shown us, a pointer in `class B` is an unnecessary level of indirection and the `A` (or just the `std::array`) should be a direct member.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very good answer. Note that, as @Jarod42 said, adding parenthesis around `new A<T, N>()` also solves it. And the points you mentioned originate indeed from the quick example I wrote.

Comment: Yeah, I added a mention of that method too, but using a type alias may be a good idea anyway in a lot of cases, so I kept that.

Comment: Yup. A small (almost unrelated) question: would you consider this a complex initialisation? Writing a lot of Swift code, it seems to me far clearer to have in-class initialisation for simple pointers...

Comment: I would, because it allocates memory outside the class. If something’s allocating resources on construction, I expect to see it in the constructor, not the class body. Partially this is because I expect the destructor and constructor to be parallel: if you delete something in the destructor I expect to see it mentioned in the constructor, and vice versa.

Comment: Good to know, might be useful. Although with smart pointers, the memory freed itself when going out of scope, right?

Comment: Yes, and I wouldn’t object as strongly to seeing a `make_unique` in a class member initialization instead of a `new`. It’s still not where I’d put it, probably, but I wouldn’t be as surprised to see it there.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your pointer in a constructor, not in-class. Like so:

```
template<typename T, int N>
class B {
public:
    B() : myA(new A<T, N>()) {}
    ~B() { delete myA; }
    A<T, N> *myA;
};
```

Or, you could simply ditch the pointer:

```
template<typename T, int N>
class B {
public:
    A<T, N> myA;
};
```

If you plan on using the pointer version, keep in mind that there are better ways to do this (`std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: It works well, thanks. Although given the standards, I don't see why we cannot use in-class initialisation. Looks like a CGG bug to me...

Comment: I agree, but it is generally always more recommended to initialize your members in a constructor instead of in-class.

Comment: Using `unique_ptr` is a good idea, but has the same issue if you *just* make that change; `std::unique_ptr<A<T, N>> myA = std::make_unique<A<T, N>>();` still fails to compile. EDIT: no, it doesn’t. I’m confused about why not, though.

Comment: @DanielH Yes obviously. I just wanted to mention that using a `std::unique_ptr` was a better idea, regardless of the original issue.

Comment: My marked edit to my comment is false; it does not compile. I’m not sure why it seemed to.

Comment: @JérémiPanneton Yes, that makes sense.